# How to put security patch on Text view?

Tags: java, android, security, textview, patch

I don't know what to say to this but I want mask or put patch on Text view.
See the picture below. I want effect like this. I've searched lot but didn't find any post with same requirement. How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: you can add an imageview over your textview

Comment: Hope This will help you https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA

Comment: Kiran Koravi , its image captcha ?

Comment: @MageshPandian  No, it's not an Image Captcha. It's like scratch area like we have recharge coupon but bit transparent

Comment: ok what functionality you need to do ?

Comment: @MageshPandian I just want to put patch on that number. Kinda of hiding thing behind curtain.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two images in one TextView Like below Code:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/pacth_icon"
/>
```

use

`android:drawableLeft`

and

`android:drawableRight`

to set  your images in `TextView`.And you can `setText` and background Image as well.